# Assigning the value of a variable inside the condition of an if statemment

Tags: javascript

While learning ES6 I stumbled upon this piece of code:

```
for (let conversion of conversions) {
  let result
  if ((result = conversion(data[i], orig[i])) !== undefined) {
    console.log(result)
    data[i] = result
  }
}
```

It took me some minutes to understand that if statement, and realize that the value of `result` is being assigned there.

So my question is, is doing the following the same?

```
  let result = conversion(data[i], orig[i])
  if (result !== undefined) {
    console.log(result)
    data[i] = result
  }
```

In which situations I should assign the value of a variable like in the first example?

Answer (score 4):

> is doing the following the same?

Yes, `let foo; if ((foo = bar) === baz)` is the same as `let foo = bar; if (foo === baz)`

> In which situations I should assign the value of a variable like in the first example?

When you want to do an amazing one-liner in code golf.

It's only really useful to write it like this very occasionally in the condition of a loop so you don't have to repeat code e.g. consider

```
foo = bar();
while (false !== foo) {
    // ..
    foo = bar();
}
```

vs

```
while (false !== (foo = bar())) {
    // ..
}
```

Doing it for an `if` is just not necessary

Comment: There is a subtle difference though: In the first snippet, `foo` is only assigned, but never accessed. It might be a setter/getter :-)

Comment: @Bergi can you create setter/getters with `let`?

Comment: No, only `with({get foo() {…}, set foo(x){…}}) { if ((foo = bar) === baz) }` would do that.